# ElasticSearch | Randomize results with same score

Tags: elasticsearch, random, elasticsearch-query

In ElasticSearch is it possible to randomize the order of search results with equal score without losing pagination?

I'm hosting a database with thousands of job candidates. When a company are searching for a particular skill (or a combination of skills), it's always the same order (and thus the candidates in the top of search results are having a huge advantage)

Example for a search query:

```
let params = {
      index: 'candidates',
      type: 'candidate',
      explain: true,
      size: size,
      from: from,
      body: {
        _source: {
          includes: ['firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName']
        },
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [/* Left out */],
            should: [/* Left out */],
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: You could use [rescoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-rescore) to randomize top-K results.

Answer (score 1):

Henry's answer is good, but I think it is easier to do:

```
        function_score: {
          query: {
            ...
          },
          random_score: {
            seed: 12345678910,
            field: '_seq_no',
            weight: 0.0001
          },
          boost_mode: 'sum'
```

So there is no need to boost the original score, just weight the random score down so that it contributes little (but still enough to break ties).

I do dislike such approach to break ties though, because even if you are contributing just a little to the score, you could still change order of results between results which do not have the same score, but have the score very close. This is why I opened [this feature request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/90652).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query, wrap your bool query in it and add a [random_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-random) function. Next step is to find the good weighting that match your needs using "boost" and "boost_mode" or "weight"...

Note that if you use filters the [output score will be 0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18273#issuecomment-218482493) so you will need to change the "boost_mode" from "multiply" to "replace", "sum" or something else...

Finally, don't forget to add a seed (and field as of ES 7.0) to the random_score to keep a [near-consistent](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1170#issuecomment-22819670) pagination

From your example I would suggest something like :

```
let params = {
      ...
      body: {
        ...
        function_score: {
          query: {
            bool: {
              must: [/* Left out */],
              should: [/* Left out */],
              boost: 100
            }
          },
          random_score: {
            seed: 12345678910,
            field: '_seq_no'
          },
          boost_mode: 'sum'
        }
      }
    };
```